# how do I dropDuplicates by ["x","y"] without shuffling a spark dataframe already partitioned by "x"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark data frame that has already been repartitioned by column x:

```
df2 = df1.reparition("x")
```

I would like to drop duplicates by x and another column without shuffling, since the shuffling is extremely long in this particular case.

```
df3 = df2.dropDuplicates(subset=["x","y"])
```

edit: Clearly the existing implementation of dropDuplicates does not support non-shuffling. Is there a way to achieve a similar results using sql windowing functions over y, assuming the data was recently partitioned by x.

Comment: Can you share `explain` that shows a shuffle related to `dropDuplicates`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think shuffle will happen but only to carry out `repartition("x")`. The subsequent `dropDuplicates()` will then sort partitions by `key=["x","y"]`, followed by aggregate to take `first` row for each key. Since all rows for `x` are already in one partition, no additional shuffling will be required.

**UPDATE**

Lets run a quick test:

```
[user@gateway ~]# pyspark
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0-cdh6.x-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9 2019 14:30:50)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame([{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 1},{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 2},{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 2},{'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 1}])
>>> df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |-- y: long (nullable = true)
 |-- z: long (nullable = true)

>>> df2 = df1.repartition("x")
>>> df3 = df2.dropDuplicates(subset=["x","y"])
>>> df3.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) HashAggregate(keys=[x#0L, y#1L], functions=[first(z#2L, false)])
+- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[x#0L, y#1L], functions=[partial_first(z#2L, false)])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(x#0L, 200)
      +- Scan ExistingRDD[x#0L,y#1L,z#2L]

>>> df3.show()
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  2|
|  1|  1|  1|
|  2|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+

>>>
```

The plan shows single `Exchange` operator (shuffle on `x`), followed by `HashAggregate`s operating on a given partition to get `partial_first` for each `x,y` pair and take the first row (without even sorting).

Comment: I confirm this answer is correct. in larger scale I got SortMergeJoin (x) and then SortAggregate([x,y])

Comment: this is brilliant. I didn't expect spark to plan well